# flexbox item's with flex all the same size even on wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having a column with results, now all the items need to flex to fill the row, now only when 1 blok wrap's it takes up the complete width of the container.

What I need to get is that all the blocks are still the same size is this possible with flexbox?

```css
.u-flexbox--spaceAround {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.u-flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}
.hotelOutlet-hotel {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotelOutlet-results u-flexbox--spaceAround">
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you've set only a min-width. try setting a max and you should see the difference!

Comment: This will not make sure all the blocks are the same size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting your divs to have a `max-width`  of `150 px` would do what you're looking for, as shown in the below snippet:

*(run in full screen mode)*

```css
.u-flexbox--spaceAround {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.u-flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}
.hotelOutlet-hotel {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotelOutlet-results u-flexbox--spaceAround">
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
  <div class="hotelOutlet-hotel u-flex-1">

  </div>
</div>
```